# Scraping: cannot extract content from webpage

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the news content from the following page, but with no success.
https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/?&search=nike

I have tried with Beautifulsoup :

```
r = requests.get("https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/?&search=nike")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
soup
```

but the content that I am looking for - the bits of news that are tagged as div class = 'card__content', do not appear in the soup output.

I also checked, but I could not find any frames to switch to.

Finally, I tried with phantomjs and the following code but with no success:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/?&search=nike"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= '~\Chromedriver\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(7)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={
    'class':'card__content'})
print(container)
```

I am running out of options, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use API

```
import requests


r = requests.get("https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/api/internal/explore/?format=json&search=nike")


print(r.json())
```

Comment: Justin, if you test it, you will see that is actually not reporting the news... just some text that always appear, not matter what is the specific url on the site

Comment: Could you write out what exactly you are trying to pull from the site?

Comment: If you look for nike on the website https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/?&search=nike you will see that appear different news articles including: "Nike says China-based supplier stopped hiring employees from northwest amid forced labour allegations, but critics say further proof is needed". I am trying to access these news

Comment: There is actually a backend API you can get into to get those results. I've modified my answer to show that it is actually really easy. ```r.json()``` returns a ```dict``` object you can parse

Comment: oh wow! I did not know that! This is great, how did you figure out about the API? and btw, why can't I capture it through beautifulsoup?

Comment: Use your browser "inspect element" feature to monitor network requests. Since the page is loaded dynamically, it pings that API to get the results and then loads them into the web site. It isn't through ```beautifulsoup``` because it's a different url alltogether and ```beautifulsoup``` parses HTML, but the API returns a pure ```json``` dict that can be easily parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you're facing this. I tried the same above but not with requests and bs4. I used `requests_html`. xpaths can be used directly in this library without any other libraries.

```
import requests_html

session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
URL = 'https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/?&search=nike'
res = session.get(URL)


divs_with_required_class = res.html.xpath(r'//div[@class="card__content"]')

for item in divs_with_required_class:
    print(f'Div {divs_with_required_class.index(item) + 1}:\n', item.text, end='\n\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

`driver.page_source` returns initial HTML-doc content no matter how long you wait (`time.sleep(7)` has no effect).

Try below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(url)
cards = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card__content' and normalize-space(.)]")))
texts = [card.text for card in cards]
print(texts)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: oh boy, I think they have got smarter? this is the error that I am getting:  MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=59818): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session/76e81f60-e7a7-11ea-80d2-3364d5a88d72/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000194B66E5730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Comment: @FilippoSebastio Can you try the same with another webDriver? Note that PhantomJS has no support/updates for 4,5 years. I strongly recommend not to use it at all

Comment: I tried with chrome webdriver, it does not return the error anymore, however it returns a list of empty strings? ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']